# How to write a vector to a json file?

Tags: json, vector, rust

How to write a vector to a JSON file in rust?

Code:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

let vec1 = vec![1.0,2.0,2.1,0.6];

let mut file = File::create("results.json").unwrap();
let data = serde_json::to_string(&vec1).unwrap();

file.write(&data);
```

Error:

```
mismatched types
expected reference `&[u8]`
   found reference `&std::string::String`rustc(E0308)
```

Comment: Doesn't `serde_json::to_string` transform it into the correct json representation?

Comment: The compiler complains because `File::write()` expects a slice of `u8`, and you're giving it a `String`. To make your code compile, change it to `file.write_all(data.as_bytes()).unwrap()`. For a better solution (that doesn't involve creating an intermediate string), refer to Sven's excellent answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of writing the data to an in-memory string first, you can also write it directly to the file:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let file = File::create("a")?;
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(file);
    serde_json::to_writer(&mut writer, &vec)?;
    writer.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

This approach has a lower memory footprint and is generally preferred. Note that you should use buffered writes to the file, since serialization could otherwise result in many small writes to the file, which would severely reduce performance.

If you need to write the data to memory first for some reason, I suggest using `serde_json::to_vec()` instead of `serde_json::to_string()`, since that function will give you a `Vec<u8>` immediately.